# Maya - check if an attributes is enabled / disabled

Tags: python, maya, mel

Since hours I try to solve a problem I have with Maya / MEL / Python.
I have a script to set values of a fluid container.

E.g. setAttr "fluidShape1.densityDissipation" 0.2

Works great...

My problem: Actually it is not possible to change the value using the interface        (see image). Is there a way to find out if the "text box" is enabled?

Thanks!!

P.S. I cant upload the image :(. But I hope you guys know what i mean

Answer (score 1):

To find out if the attribute is settable, use

```
getAttr -settable your_object.your_attribute
```

it will return 1 if you can set the attribute using `setAttr` and 0 if you can't.

If the value is grayed out in the UI the attribute is *locked*, you can unlock it with

```
setAttr -lock 0  your_object.your_attribute
```

If the value is purple in the UI it's driven by a connection of some kind, you'll need to use the hypergraph or the `listConnections` command to find out what's driving it and decide if you want to override the connection.

Answer (score 1):

I already tried the **-settable** flag, but for some reason this is not working in my case.

Ok, lets say I create a FluidContainer. The **density** is set to zero, by using this command:

```
setAttr "fluidShape1.densityMethod" 0;
```

By using the -settable flag

```
getAttr -settable "fluidShapeq.densityScale"
```

the result is **1.** But I can not change the corresponding slider.
But still it is possible to change the values by using setAttr... That is confusing for me!

Answer (score 0):

ok I think I found a "solution" for my problem, but I think I can do better.
I use the following command to get the "grougID" of the slider and the field:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
txt = "attrFieldSliderGrp214" 
cmds.attrFieldSliderGrp( txt, q=True, l=True ) # Density Scale
```

And now I can usethe enable field by:

```
gray = cmds.attrFieldSliderGrp(txt, q=True, en=True ) # True/False
```

Comment: Ok, this is also not working. The problem is that "214" is not always the number for the Density Scale Slider... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me.

```
def gui():
    cmds.window()
    cmds.columnLayout( adjustableColumn=True )
    #since density support only upto 3 setting max to 3
    getCurrentInd = int(cmds.getAttr("fluidShape1.densityMethod"))
    cmds.intSlider( min=0, max=3, value=getCurrentInd, step=1, cc=updateDens)
    cmds.showWindow()

def updateDens(value):
    cmds.setAttr("fluidShape1.densityMethod", value)
gui()
```

Comment: Ok that work's but it's not what I mean. getCurrentInd = int(cmds.getAttr("fluidShape1.densityDissipation")) returns 0 no matter if "densityMethod" = 0,1,2,3 ... E.g.: 0 --> Slider disabled. 1 2 --> Dlider enabled

Comment: I don't understand what you saying getCurrentInd = int(cmds.getAttr("fluidShape1.densityDissipation"))  this will return value and it will set the slider for sure :)

Comment: Yes, you are totally right! This lines of code return the value of the slider. But I would like to know if the slider is enabled (gray) or disabled (light gray). If the slider is disabled, my plugin should not set "random" a value...

Answer (score 0):

By Interface if I understand that you mean the `AttributeEditor`, you could try this.

```
import pymel.core as pc
def findAEFieldByLabel(label='Dissipation', field_type=pc.ui.AttrFieldSliderGrp):   
    for i in pc.ui.PyUI('MainAttributeEditorLayout').walkChildren():
        if isinstance(i, pc.ui.RowLayout):
            name = i.name()
            try:
                grp = field_type(name)
                if grp.getLabel() == label:
                    return grp
            except:
                pass
print findAEFieldByLabel().getEnable()
```

I used `pymel` here because it helps you find the type of a python ui. Well ... not quite however! because it recognized `attrFieldSliderGrps` as `RowLayouts`

Comment: Thank you so much for this code snippet. That is exactly what I was looking for!!

Comment: Hey, I found one small problem. The state is only correct, when the user "opens" the spezific tab. From scratch, it is always "enabled"

Comment: Ofcourse, UI can only be queried if it is there. What can always be queried reliably is the underlying node. Isn't the approach by @theodox something that you should be going for?

Comment: I can not see your point. Of coure I can ask if the textBox is settable or not. But that is not what i would like to have. Your code is exactly doing what i would like to have... :) The only code I would need now is: "Open the e.g. Velocity ToolBoxItem - which refreshes the view". But is that possible with MEL/Python ?